# Swift - How to create dynamic labels in stackview?

Tags: arrays, swift, dynamic, label, stackview

I'm trying to create a stackview with dynamic number of lables.

I tried with:

```swift
let nValues: String = "A , B, C, D"

if let someArray = nValues.components(separatedBy: ",") {
         let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            for nValue in someArray {
              label.text = nValue
              label.textColor = .black
              nutrientValueLabel?.backgroundColor = .white
              myStackView.addSubview(label)
              print(nValue)
     }
 }
```

But i get only:

```swift
A
B
C
D
```

and empty stackView. 
I don't know what is my mistake.

Comment: Might be your stack view is not expanding, give your stack view background colour to find that. If that's not the issue then trying using "stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)" instead of addSubView to add label.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I created my label at the beginning. 
I put it in the for loop. And used

```
myStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
```

instead of

```
myStackView.addSubview(label)
```

So This is the whole code:

```
let nValues: String = "A , B, C, D"

if let someArray = nValues.components(separatedBy: ",") {
      for nValue in someArray {
          let label: UILabel = UILabel()
          label.text = nValue
          label.textColor = .black
          nutrientValueLabel?.backgroundColor = .white
          myStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
     }
 }
```